# Replacing \n with %0A

Tags: php, url

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {  
        $send_to  = $_POST['number'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        echo $message;
        $url ="http://assssdewweas.com/Send.aspx?userid=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&clientid=3589&senderid=asdodas&asdr=91send_to&smsmessage=$message";
        $url = str_replace("\n","%0A",$url);
        $url = str_replace(' ','+',$url);
        echo $url;
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $curl_scraped_page;
    }
?>
```

It works fine but the problem is whenever I pass value in `$message` variable it echo:
http://assssdewweas.com/Send.aspx?userid=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&clientid=3589&senderid=asdodas&asdr=91send_to&smsmessage=$message

Instead of:

```
hhttp://assssdewweas.com/Send.aspx?userid=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&clientid=3589&senderid=asdodas&asdr=91send_to&smsmessage=$message
```

I don't want any space between `hello` and `%0A`. Please help how to fix it.

Comment: try trim($message) and then append to your url

Comment: You shouldn't post your username/password on a public forum.

Answer (score 2):

Use `url_encode()` instead of replacing which is not the right way to do it

[url_encode() Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

And instead of passing so many information in your url use `method=post` instead of `get`, because `get` method has limit of passing the data in the address bar where `post` doesn't, moreover your data will be hidden if you use `post` method

Comment: @user1460815 You should mark the answer as correct so others can refer